# Check if flags are set in big integer

Tags: javascript, flags

I have two flags "32" and "64" which need to be checked if they're included inside an integer variable.

Therefore I'm using the following code which is working fine with "small integers". For example if the integer variable is "33555378" it outputs the right results.

Now I have the problem that the integer variable is "12261800583900083122" and the script doesn't seem to work correctly.

How do I check if flags are set in big integers correctly?

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toax1bpe/).

**Code:**

```
var flags = {
    Horde: 32, 
    Allianz: 64,
}

var flag = 12261800583900083122;

if ((flag & flags.Horde) == flags.Horde && (flag & flags.Allianz) == flags.Allianz) {
     console.log('Both');
} else if ((flag & flags.Allianz) == flags.Allianz) {
     console.log('Allianz');
} else if ((flag & flags.Horde) == flags.Horde) {
     console.log('Horde');
} else {
     console.log('Nothing');
}
```

Comment: Big integer constants need to have "n" at the end.

Comment: why not split the `flag` to a couple of numbers, so the issue won't apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `BigInt` (adding `n` after numbers) for both `flags` and `flag` can fix your problem;

```
var flags = {
    Horde: 32n, 
    Allianz: 64n,
}

var flag = 12261800583900083122n;

if ((flag & flags.Horde) == flags.Horde && (flag & flags.Allianz) == flags.Allianz) {
     console.log('Both');
} else if ((flag & flags.Allianz) == flags.Allianz) {
     console.log('Allianz');
} else if ((flag & flags.Horde) == flags.Horde) {    
     console.log('Horde');
} else {
     console.log('Nothing');
}
```

This results as `Horde`.